# gcc using unlink and readdir, 7 days old files needs to be deleted

Tags: gcc

Using this code fetched from google.

```
 #include <dirent.h>

   #include <sys/types.h>

   #include <unistd.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

       struct dirent *entry;

       DIR *dp;

       chdir("/mnt/shared");

       dp = opendir(".");

       while( (entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL ) {

        if ( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") &&strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") ){

            unlink(entry->d_name);

        }
    }
   }`
```

In this could it be possible to delete files older than 7 days from the current date?

In perl i tried as follows, but wondering this could be achived with your help?

```
    my $now = time();       

    my $DATEAGE = 60*60*24*7;  

      for my $file (@file_list) {

        my @stats = stat($file);

       if ($now-$stats[9] > $DATEAGE) { 

       print "$file\n";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the full string of the file and use several [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (notably [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) ; read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   struct dirent *entry;
   DIR *dp;
   time_t weekago;
   time(&weekago);
   weekago -= 86400*7;
   dp = opendir("/mnt/shared");
   if (!dp) { perror("/mnt/shared"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   while( (entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL ) {
    if ( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".")
     && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") ){
  char buf[256];
  if (snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),
           "/mnt/shared/%s", entry->d_name)
      >=sizeof(buf))
    { fprintf(stderr, "too long path %s\n", buf);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
  struct stat st;
  if (stat(buf,&st)) {
    perror(buf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };
  if ((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG  // a plain file
      && (st.st_mtime < weekago))
    {
      if (remove(buf)) perror(buf);
    }
    }
}
```

My *untested* code above is imperfect (and not very well indented): it don't handle file paths wider than 255. But you could improve it, e.g. using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) to build the path in heap (then you'll need to `free` it).

Practically speaking, use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). If you need to recurse in a file tree in C, use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Comment: Tried this, while compiling , getting the following error                           "# gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:13: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'
test.c:13: error: 'EXIT_FAILURE' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:13: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:13: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:22: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' test.c:24: error: storage size of 'st' isn't known
test.c:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration

Comment: That was a missing `<stdlib.h>` inclusion. Fixed. BTW, you really should RTFM e.g. [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html). Also avoid naming your program `test`.